# Unexpected end of file error in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I'm doing this for an assignment and just cannot figure out why I keep getting the unexpected end of file error. Its just meant to be a simple menu with an emil program. I only have one if and the correct one accompanying fi. I'm sure it's something super simple but I've just been banging my head against the wall.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # menu interface for simple controls

    until  [[ "$userIn" = q ]]

        do
    
            echo -e "/n COMMAND MENU\n"
            echo " A. Email"
            echo
            echo " B. Users Currently On"
            echo
            echo " C. Date and Time"
            echo
            echo " D. Calendar"
            echo
            echo " E. Currently Logged in as: "
            echo
            echo " F. Contents of working Dir"
            echo
            echo " G. Find the IP of a Web Address"
            echo
            echo " H. Fortune"
            echo
            echo " I. Display a file's contents"
            echo
            echo " Q. Exit"
            echo
            echo " Enter a Letter: " answer
            echo
    #
            read "$mOption"
            case "$answer" in
                a|A)
                    echo "Welcome to the Emailer!"
                    echo
                    echo "Enter your message. Press <ENTER> when finished."
                    read $mContent
                    echo
                    echo "Enter the email address you are sending to and press <ENTER>"
                    read $mAddress
                    echo
                    echo "Do you want to attach a file?"
                    read $ATTACH
                    echo

                    if ["$ATTACH" = "Y"|"y"]
                    then
                        echo "Type the name of the file to be attached and press <ENTER>"
                        read $mAttach
                        mail -s "$mContent" "$mAddress"<"$mAttach"
                        echo         
                        echo "Your mail will be sent with the designated attachment!"
                        echo
    
                    else
                        mail -s "$mContent" "$mAddress"
                        echo
                        echo "Your Email has been sent!"
                    fi
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

                b|B)
                    echo "Users Currently On: "
                    who
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

                c|C)
                    echo
                    date
                    echo
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

                d|D)
                    echo
                    calendar
                    echo
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

                e|E)
                    echo
                    pwd
                    echo
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

                f|F)
                    echo
                    ls
                    echo
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

                g|G)
                    echo "Type the Web Address and press <ENTER>:"
                    read $mWeb
                    echo
                    echo "Here are your results:"
                    nslookup $mWeb
                    echo
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

                h|H)
                    echo
                    fortune
                    echo
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

                i|I)
                    echo "Enter the name of the file you would like to see and press <ENTER>:"
                    read $mFile
                    echo
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

                j|J)
                    echo "Have A Nice Day!"
                    echo "Goodbye!"
                    userIn = q
                    ;;

                m|M)
                    echo -e "/n COMMAND MENU\n"
                    echo " A. Email"
                    echo
                    echo " B. Users Currently On"
                    echo
                    echo " C. Date and Time"
                    echo
                    echo " D. Calendar"
                    echo
                    echo " E. Currently Logged in as: "
                    echo
                    echo " F. Contents of working Dir"
                    echo
                    echo " G. Find the IP of a Web Address"
                    echo
                    echo " H. Fortune"
                    echo
                    echo " I. Display a file's contents"
                    echo
                    echo " Q. Exit"
                    echo
                    echo " Enter a Letter: "
                    echo
                    ;;

                *)
                    echo "Sorry, that wasn't a valid selection"
                    echo "Select a new option, press M to display the menu, or press Q to quit"
                    echo
                    ;;

    esac
```

Comment: So you have `do` on top of the script. Where's `done`?

Comment: Where would I put that within the code? I kinda had figured the until would cover it.

Comment: On the end. The syntax is `until condition; do stuff; done`

Comment: I tried plopping a "done" at the end but that spits an error of "syntax error near unexpected token 'newline' '    done'

Comment: Post your script on https://www.shellcheck.net/ and go through all mistakes.

Comment: That was helpful enough to get it to run (it now infinitely prints the menu), but a few things seem like they either fully do not pply or have no solution. Mostly around " if ["$ATTACH" = "Y"|"y"] "

Comment: `if ["$ATTACH" = "Y"|"y"] ` -> `if [ "$ATTACH" = "Y" ] || [ "$ATTACH" = "y" ]`

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!!
That was most of what I couldnt figure out. 

Everything is working now except that it displays the whole menu again at every user input. Is there a way for me to fix that?

Comment: In which way do you want it fixed, i. e. when exactly do you want the menu displayed?